# how to sort array in php based on its name?

Tags: php

I have an array like this

```
Array
(
    [bms] => Array
        (
            [0] => 123456_bms_for__on__(10-06-2015_18-57).pdf
        )

    [fr] => Array
        (
            [0] => 123456_fr_on_09-21-2015_(09-22-2015_11-46).pdf
        )

    [pcm] => Array
        (
            [0] => 123456_pcm_for_vignesh_on__(10-12-2015_12-30).pdf
        )

    [fds] => Array
        (
            [0] => 123456_fds_ext_for__on__(08-25-2015_10-23).pdf
        )

    [dr] => Array
        (
            [0] => 123456_dr_for__on___(10-23-2015_13-06).pdf
        )

)
```

And i want to order this array into (bms,dr,fds,pcm,fr) order

```
Array
(
    [bms] => Array
        (
            [0] => 123456_bms_for__on__(10-06-2015_18-57).pdf
        )
    [dr] => Array
        (
            [0] => 123456_dr_for__on___(10-23-2015_13-06).pdf
        )
    [fds] => Array
        (
            [0] => 123456_fds_ext_for__on__(08-25-2015_10-23).pdf
        )
    [pcm] => Array
        (
            [0] => 123456_pcm_for_vignesh_on__(10-12-2015_12-30).pdf
        )

    [fr] => Array
        (
            [0] => 123456_fr_on_09-21-2015_(09-22-2015_11-46).pdf
        )
)
```

Please help me to sort out array and help me to achieve the array in new order
How to arrange array based on its key value

Comment: use ksort() to acheive

Comment: not in alphabetic order....it will arrange as per given array

Comment: if you have predefined above keys which will not increase in future you can think about reconstructing the array.

Comment: @ uchiha..... I want order (bms,dr,fds,pcm,fr) ... but result is (bms,dr,fds,fr,pcm)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use `uksort` like as

```
$pos = ['bms', 'dr', 'fds', 'pcm', 'fr'];
uksort($arr, function ($a, $b) use ($pos) {
    foreach ($pos as $value) {
        if ($value == $a) {
            return 0;
            break;
        }
        if ($value == $b) {
            return 1;
            break;
        }
    }
});
```

[<kbd>**Demo**</kbd>](https://eval.in/457700)

Answer (score 2):

You can use **[`uksort`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.uksort.php)** PHP function.

> **uksort()** will sort the keys of an array using a user-supplied comparison function. If the array you wish to sort needs to be sorted by some non-trivial criteria, you should use this function.

```
$sortOrder = array("bms", "dr", "fds", "pcm", "fr");

uksort($yourArray, function($a, $b) use ($sortOrder) {
    return array_search($a, $sortOrder) - array_search($b, $sortOrder); 
});
```

Working [IDEOne](http://ideone.com/OTpQiq) or [eval.in](https://eval.in/457734) demos.

Comment: Even shorter now, without `global` :)